# Как получить данные страницы после перенаправления?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, qiwi

**Я провожу get запрос и хочу получить данные с сайта. Но сначала меня кидает на сайт, на котром вылезает строка на секунду с просьбой подождать, а после уже проходит перенаправление на нужный мне сайт. А при выводе данных сайта(**`print(req.text)`**), выводится как раз ненужная мне строчка при перенаправлении.
И вопрос, как мне получить данные сайта, уже после перенаправления?**

*Надпись при перенаправлении:*
[image: Надпись при перенаправлении]

```py
import requests
request = requests.Session()
req = request.get("https://oplata.qiwi.com/create?publicKey=FAKEPUBLICKEY&amount=11&billId=ASDF1234-asdf-ZXCV-VCXZ-qwertyuiopfg&comment=test_connect")
req.encoding = "utf-8"
print(req.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Перенаправление и история](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history):
можно использовать [Response.history](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response.history) свойство - это список, содержащий [Response](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response) объекты, созданные в процессе завершения запроса, отсортированный от самого старого до самого последнего ответа.

Например, GitHub перенаправляет все HTTP-запросы на HTTPS:

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://github.com/')

>>> r.url
'https://github.com/'

>>> r.status_code
200

>>> r.history
[<Response [301]>]
```

Если вы используете GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT, PATCH или DELETE, вы можете отключить обработку перенаправления с помощью allow_redirect sпараметра:

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://github.com/', allow_redirects=False)

>>> r.status_code
301

>>> r.history
[]
```

Если вы используете HEAD, вы также можете включить перенаправление:

```
>>> r = requests.head('http://github.com/', allow_redirects=True)

>>> r.url
'https://github.com/'

>>> r.history
[<Response [301]>]
```

Comment: Не совсем получается... И пробовал и с `allow_redirects=False` и с `allow_redirects=True`, `print(req.text)` выдаёт всё равно одно и тоже.
Можете сами проверить с моей ссылкой выше.

Comment: И да, мне нужно получить не URL, а само содержимое страницы(после перенаправления)